# How do I refresh a Visualforce Component in a Lightning layout?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, opportunity, refresh

I am using the Lightning Opportunity page and have a custom Visualforce Component in the right rail that queries some of the fields on the Opportunity. But when I edit the Opp, only the details portion refreshes. The VF Component does not, therefore it shows out-of-date information. Is there a way to force the refresh of all components when a record is edited and saved?

Answer (score 1):

There is no interaction and communication between your Lightning Opportunity page and your VF component. Your VF page is embedded inside an iframe. Salesforce didn't build such a thing [yet]. But that would be fantastic.

I think you best option would be to use setTimeout in javascript and refresh the information on your VF page every x seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){ refreshOpportunityInfo() }, 3000);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp